Rational maps from the circle to the unitary group (energy-preserving convolutive mixtures)
Consider a rational map $A : S^1 \to U(n)$, i.e. a matrix of rational functions such that evaluation at any $z \in S^1 \subset \mathbf C$ is unitary. These objects show up in digital signal processing as the transfer functions of energy-preserving filterbanks (convolutive mixing operations) – in that context they're referred to as "paraunitary matrices."
I'm able to prove that any such $A$ can be decomposed as
$$ A(z) = A(1) \prod_{j = 1}^N \Big((\mathrm{Id} - v_j v_j^\dagger) + f_{\alpha_j}(z) v_j v_j^\dagger \Big) \qquad \text{where} \qquad f_\alpha(z) = \frac{\overline \alpha - 1}{1 - \alpha}\frac{\alpha - z}{1 - \overline \alpha z} $$
for some complex numbers $\{\alpha_j\}$ and vectors $\{v_j\} \subset \mathbf C^n$. Is this result known, or has anyone run into these objects in other areas of research? I wasn't able to find anything in my search of the signal processing / control theory / loop groups literature.

The collection of degree-$k$ "polynomial paraunitaries," $$ P_k = \{ A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbf C[z]) \mid A(S^1) \subset U(n) \text{ and } \deg \det A = k\}, $$ forms a real algebraic variety, cut out by the equations $A(z^{-1})^\dagger A(z) = \mathrm{Id}$. By the decomposition above there's a surjection from $U(n) \times (\mathbf{CP}^{n-1})^k$ to $P_k$, but the map is not injective since consecutive terms in the product above will commute when $v_j,v_{j+1}$ are orthogonal.
Is anything known about the geometry of $P_k$? I'd like to know both about its intrinsic geometry, and also how it sits inside $\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbf C[z])$; I'd like to be able to find the point in $P_k$ that is $\ell^2$-closest to a given matrix $B$ of polynomials. Any references would be appreciated!
